# Need to know what is the table that contains the Qty On Hand in Odoo

Tags: sql, postgresql, odoo

I need to build a report collect the QtyOnHand in the store groped based on Vendor => Shipment

I am trying to build sql query

this code is not working:

```sql
CREATE or REPLACE VIEW purchase_custom_report as ( 
            WITH currency_rate as (
            SELECT
                r.currency_id,
                COALESCE(r.company_id, c.id) as company_id,
                r.rate,
                r.name AS date_start,
                (SELECT name FROM res_currency_rate r2
                 WHERE r2.name > r.name AND
                       r2.currency_id = r.currency_id AND
                       (r2.company_id is null or r2.company_id = c.id)
                 ORDER BY r2.name ASC
                 LIMIT 1) AS date_end
            FROM res_currency_rate r
            JOIN res_company c ON (r.company_id is null or r.company_id = c.id)
        )
                SELECT
                    min(l.id) as id,
                    s.date_order as date_order,
                    s.partner_id as partner_id,
                    s.user_id as user_id,
                    s.company_id as company_id,
                    t.list_price as std_price,
                    l.product_id,
                    p.temp_qty as available_in_store,
                    p.product_tmpl_id,
                    t.categ_id as category_id,
                    s.currency_id,
                    case when invoice_status='invoiced' then True else False end as po_paid_flag,
                    t.uom_id as product_uom,
                    t.standard_price as cost,
                    l.price_subtotal/l.product_qty as real_price,
                    l.price_subtotal/l.product_qty - t.standard_price as profit_val,
                    s.date_order as purchase_id_date,
                    -- ((l.price_subtotal/COALESCE(NULLIF(l.product_qty, 0), 1.0)) - t.standard_price) * 100/ COALESCE(NULLIF(t.standard_price, 0), 1.0) as profit_percentage,
                    p.temp_qty * t.standard_price as stock_value,
                    sum(l.product_qty/u.factor*u2.factor) as unit_quantity,
                    sum(l.price_unit / COALESCE(NULLIF(cr.rate, 0), 1.0) * l.product_qty)::decimal(16,2) as price_total,
                    (sum(l.product_qty * l.price_unit / COALESCE(NULLIF(cr.rate, 0), 1.0))/NULLIF(sum(l.product_qty/u.factor*u2.factor),0.0))::decimal(16,2) as price_average
         FROM ( 
            purchase_order_line l
                join purchase_order s on (l.order_id=s.id)
                join res_partner partner on s.partner_id = partner.id
                    left join product_product p on (l.product_id=p.id)
                        left join product_template t on (p.product_tmpl_id=t.id)
                        LEFT JOIN ir_property ip ON (ip.name='standard_price' AND ip.res_id=CONCAT('product.product,',p.id) AND ip.company_id=s.company_id)
                left join uom_uom u on (u.id=l.product_uom)
                left join uom_uom u2 on (u2.id=t.uom_id)
                left join stock_quant sq on (sq.product_id = p.id)
                left join currency_rate cr on (cr.currency_id = s.currency_id and
                    cr.company_id = s.company_id and
                    cr.date_start <= coalesce(s.date_order, now()) and
                    (cr.date_end is null or cr.date_end > coalesce(s.date_order, now())))
         ) 
            GROUP BY
                s.company_id,
                s.user_id,
                s.partner_id,
                s.currency_id,
                l.price_unit,
                l.price_subtotal,
                l.date_planned,
                l.product_uom,
                l.product_id,
                p.product_tmpl_id,
                t.categ_id,
                s.date_order,
                u.uom_type,
                u.category_id,
                t.uom_id,
                u.id,
                t.list_price,
                p.temp_qty,
                t.standard_price,
                l.product_qty,
                s.invoice_status,
                s.date_order
         )
```

What I am expecting to have is the table & field name and I will do the rest

Answer (score 0):

**It's nowhere on the database as it is a computed field.**

See `<path_to_v12>/addons/stock/models/product.py`

```
 21 class Product(models.Model):
 22     _inherit = "product.product"
...
 26     qty_available = fields.Float(
 27         'Quantity On Hand', compute='_compute_quantities', search='_search_qty_available',
 28         digits=dp.get_precision('Product Unit of Measure'),
 29         help="Current quantity of products.\n"
 30              "In a context with a single Stock Location, this includes "
 31              "goods stored at this Location, or any of its children.\n"
 32              "In a context with a single Warehouse, this includes "
 33              "goods stored in the Stock Location of this Warehouse, or any "
 34              "of its children.\n"
 35              "stored in the Stock Location of the Warehouse of this Shop, "
 36              "or any of its children.\n"
 37              "Otherwise, this includes goods stored in any Stock Location "
 38              "with 'internal' type.")
...
489     def _compute_quantities(self):
490         res = self._compute_quantities_dict()
491         for template in self:
492             template.qty_available = res[template.id]['qty_available']
493             template.virtual_available = res[template.id]['virtual_available']
494             template.incoming_qty = res[template.id]['incoming_qty']
495             template.outgoing_qty = res[template.id]['outgoing_qty']
496 
497     def _product_available(self, name, arg):
498         return self._compute_quantities_dict()
499 
500     def _compute_quantities_dict(self):
501         # TDE FIXME: why not using directly the function fields ?
502         variants_available = self.mapped('product_variant_ids')._product_available()
503         prod_available = {}
504         for template in self:
505             qty_available = 0
506             virtual_available = 0
507             incoming_qty = 0
508             outgoing_qty = 0
509             for p in template.product_variant_ids:
510                 qty_available += variants_available[p.id]["qty_available"]
511                 virtual_available += variants_available[p.id]["virtual_available"]
512                 incoming_qty += variants_available[p.id]["incoming_qty"]
513                 outgoing_qty += variants_available[p.id]["outgoing_qty"]
514             prod_available[template.id] = {
515                 "qty_available": qty_available,
516                 "virtual_available": virtual_available,
517                 "incoming_qty": incoming_qty,
518                 "outgoing_qty": outgoing_qty,
519             }
520         return prod_available
```